# Oracle indexes - Does it make sense to create an index that is a subset of another one's leading columns

Tags: oracle, database-indexes

I ran Oracle Grid Control in Oracle Applications (12c release 1) to analyse a slow running report. It's suggestion is to implement an index, however the index (`assignment_action_id` on `pay_run_results`) is a subset of another index already on the table (consisting of `assignment_action_id`, `element_type_id`, `source_type`, `status`).

Is there any sense to implementing this index? Would it make the query faster due to having to read less index blocks?

Comment: It may not be easy to tell as to what the optimizer is going to choose without knowing the distribution of data. I suggest you to run an explain plan on the query that you would frequently use with and without the suggested indexes and see the impact of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like slightly odd advice from the tuner. If your run this slow report a lot then it may be worth the cost of maintaining an extra index.

If you want to test whether the suggested index would make deliver a better execution plan for the query but don't want to invest the time and crunch actually *building* it why not test it using the virtual index capability? This is a neat way of adding an index definition to a table and seeing what the generated plan looks like. Tim Hall has a good introduction on his Oracle-Base site. [Check it out](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/virtual-indexes).

> Would it make the query faster due to having to read less index blocks?

If the query uses an index range scan or full fast scan then probably 'yes'. But before you build an other index you should consider compression. Given a compound index in which the leading column is the least selective (and the trailing column is most selective) compression can make the index much smaller. With a four column index you could potentially build the index with `compress 3`.

However, there's something about the column naming convention which makes me think that `assignment_action_id` is not the least selective column, in which case compression won't help at all (and could make things worse).

Comment: The Oracle index is indeed not compressed. Is it a good idea to question the wisdom of the developers at Oracle? In my experience they're pretty clever and normally have good reasons for doing things; although I sometimes see atrocious things like apis without error handlers.

Comment: To be honest, the Oracle tuning advisor is way smarter than me. But that doesn't mean it's right all the time :-D   In this case I'm not questioning whether the index might improve the running time of the query. It's just that the advice exists **in isolation**. You need to consider the total cost of building that index in scope of your application. I have amended my answer with a suggestion to try a virtual index. That would give you more comfort that the suggested index will work (or not).